# how to show file on asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, xml-serialization

how to get file on asp.net form so that user can download it?
suppose i have created one excel file and i want to upload it on form so that user can download it, fill the details when they are offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt"); 
 Response.WriteFile(@"test.txt");
 Response.End();
```

Otherwise if it's a specific file you can use a normal `<a href="">Download Me</a>`and point it to the files location.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fileupload component. I would store the file locally on the server and then display a list of the uploaded files.the list would be a list of hyperlinkswhich you can link directly to the uploaded files so when the user clicks on one, the file download begins automatically using the standard browser behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in one of your directories under the application root folder and then you can simply place an `anchor tag` to let user download the file, like

`<a href="/Files/abc.xls">abc</a>`